# Insert a dict in cassandra DB

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, cassandra, nosql

I have a cassandra database with a keyspace that looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE custumer_events_service.events(
    acceptFirstContactDuration decimal,
    currentTime timestamp,
    visitorIdentifier text,
    PRIMARY KEY (visitorIdentifier, currentTime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (currentTime DESC);
```

And a python dict

```py
{u'acceptFirstContactDuration': 0,
 u'currentTime': u'2016-02-18T11:51:55.468Z',
 u'12eca72928845aae26268f431b8c75b2564d7919c916e',}
```

Is there a way to insert this dict directly with `cassandra-driver`? I am looking for something like in mongodb

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> post = {"author": "Mike",
...         "text": "My first blog post!",
...         "tags": ["mongodb", "python", "pymongo"],
...         "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}

>>> posts = db.posts
>>> post_id = posts.insert_one(post).inserted_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could manually construct a `CQL` insert statement iterating over the keys and values in the dictionary, but a [`cqlengine` `Model`](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cqlengine/models.html) is probably more appropriate to use than a `dict`, and it is easy to populate a `Model` with the values from the `dict`.

You can define the `Model` like so (extending it with all of your columns):

```
class CustomerEventsServiceEvent(Model):
    __table_name__ = "customer_events_service.events"

    acceptFirstContactDuration = columns.Decimal()
    allSeenPageCount = columns.Decimal()
    callAcceptedCount = columns.Decimal()
```

If `d` is the name of your dictionary variable, then

```
event = CustomerEventsServiceEvent(**d)
event.save()
```

is the equivalent of your MongoDB operation.

Comment: Cool, I have two question: 1) what the ** mean before the dict? 2) is there a way to insert a list of dicts ( with 20000 elements ) in one batch into cassandra this way? Thanks in advance

Comment: `**` unpacks the dictionary into keyword arguments.  Many functions in Python are defined as taking **kwargs, which means they can take an arbitrary list of arguments, and `**` before a variable is the way to unpack the dictionary into these arguments.

You can use a [Batch Query](https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/queryset.html#batch-queries) to batch all of these updates together.

Comment: Oups, I got this `TypeError: deserialize() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)` on `CustomerEventsServiceEvent(**d)`

Comment: It looks like that might be related to this very recent issue? https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-354 - in which case, you might want to update to the latest version of the driver when that fix goes in, or unfortunately pre-process your datetime field to be a python datetime instead of the ISO 8601 string.