# How to insert a nested dict into Cassandra

Tags: python, database, dictionary, cassandra

Hi I have Meetup data in Python dictionary and am trying to insert it into Cassandra DB. I found this link ([Insert a dict in cassandra DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486689/insert-a-dict-in-cassandra-db)) showing how to do this but the dictionary is a flat dict. How could you insert a nested dictionary? I want to make it non-nested (picking several data from the dictionary)

Borrowing the link's example, I'm not sure what the `columns.` can be in real cases.

```
class CustomerEventsServiceEvent(Model):
    __table_name__ = "customer_events_service.events"

    acceptFirstContactDuration = columns.Decimal()
    allSeenPageCount = columns.Decimal()
    callAcceptedCount = columns.Decimal()
```

Could someone help?

Sample dictionary (just one event from many events in my dict):

```
{u'description': u'<p>In this class, you will be guided through a series of yoga poses (asanas), which are intended to increase spatial awareness, balance, strength, and flexibility. </p>\n<p><b>Each week, a different blend of essential oils will be diffused through the studio. </b></p>\n<p><i><b>$11.00 for 1 hour of Aromatherapy Yoga</b></i> <br></p>\n<p>The class utilizes a variety of breathing techniques (pranayama), which are designed to regulate the heart rate and decrease mental tension. This is an alignment-focused class, typically beginning and ending with a restorative posture, followed by a flowing sequence of movements that coordinate with the breath (vinyasa).</p>',
 u'duration': 3600000,
 u'event_url': u'http://www.meetup.com/Denver-Holistic-Health-Spiritual-Meetup/events/229141613/',
 u'group': {u'category': {u'id': 14,
                          u'name': u'health/wellbeing',
                          u'shortname': u'health-wellbeing'},
            u'city': u'Englewood',
            u'country': u'us',
            u'group_lat': 39.65,
            u'group_lon': -104.98,
            u'id': 19558352,
            u'join_mode': u'open',
            u'name': u'Denver Holistic Health/ Spiritual Meetup',
            u'state': u'CO',
            u'urlname': u'Denver-Holistic-Health-Spiritual-Meetup'},
 u'id': u'229141613',
 u'maybe_rsvp_count': 0,
 u'mtime': 1456793890358,
 u'name': u'Aromatherapeutic Yoga',
 u'payment_required': u'0',
 u'rsvp_limit': 10,
 u'status': u'upcoming',
 u'time': 1456873200000,
 u'utc_offset': -25200000,
 u'venue': {u'address_1': u'3358 Larimer st., Denver, CO 80205',
            u'city': u'Denver',
            u'country': u'us',
            u'lat': 39.765701,
            u'lon': -104.975655,
            u'name': u'Integrative Health Denver',
            u'state': u'CO'},
 u'venue_visibility': u'public',
 u'visibility': u'public',
 u'yes_rsvp_count': 4}
```

Comment: Like most data modeling in cassandra, the answer will depend on how you need to query it. So, how do you need to query it? Are you going to need to access the whole nested dict as one element? Just one piece? Do you need to search it? When you update, are you updating the whole thing or just one field?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jeff :) I'll need a few pieces of information and so updating just a few fields would be ideal. Could you give me some advice?